# Expected null or template in return value from inclusion function when update to meteor 0.8

Tags: meteor

I was following the instructions (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze) and trying to upgrade the project from meteor 0.7.2 to meteor0.8.1.3, but meet some errors and exceptions.

Errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected null or template in return value from inclusion function, found: false localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?f49560fc90a8d71b7637d9596696078881b8c812:72
```

this errors comes from helper.js which has code as following:

```
UI.registerHelper('renderHeader', function () {

   if (settingsSubscription.ready()) {
       return Template.header;
  }else {
      return "";
  }
});
```

and in index.html I use *{{renderHeader}}* to achive the template. I think the error means the function return a null template when settingSubscrition is not ready. So what template should I return when settingSubscription is not ready?

Comment: Hi, do you have any ideas, @Tom Coleman

Answer (score 3):

Since Meteor 0.8 templates are not functions, but objects so you can't insert templates the way you used to.
You should take a look at the [Blaze rendering engine](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze) which was introduced as part of Meteor 0.8 and handles rendering quite differently than the old Spark engine - where your code would have worked before.

I also recommend the most popular package yet, [Iron-Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) which would help you render your layout (and do much more) in a very robust way.

Comment: Yes, I am referring that guide to update to meteor 0.8.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you check out https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#templatefoo-is-not-a-function-and-does-not-return-a-string

In your case, you'd just do something like

```
UI.registerHelper('renderHeader', function () {
 if (GroundDB.ready())
   return Template.header;
})
```

And call it like

```
{{> renderHeader}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the exception still exists.